# A better way to navigate my music collection

Tags: itunes, music

In the Apple Music app, I like the Artist view, because it allows me to navigate to an artist quickly. But if I have a lot of albums from the selected Artist, I might have to scroll quite a bit to find a certain album. That's because for each album all songs are displayed next to the album. Is there a way to truncate the song list in the Artist view?

I kind of like the Album view too, its quite compact, but there doesn't seem to be a way to show albums only of a certain Artist. Ideally, I would like to select an Artist, and then have the Album view with albums only for that artist. Is there a way to customize either the Artist view or the Album view to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Songs view and use the column browser (in the View->Column Browser menu)

then you can choose the artist in one column, iTunes (now Apple Music) then just shows the albums for that one artist in another column (and only the songs from that artist) and from that last column choose the album.

For example:

[image: iTunes on Song view]

In iTunes the songs view used to be the main view and I think allowed more control but Music has dumbed things down and you have to use the other views sometimes.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the Column Browser menu in Songs view. So, does that mean the way I wanted it is not possible?

Comment: I am confused your description seems to be exactly met by the songs vioew. If it is not you need to explain what is missing

Comment: Yes, functionally your solution does what I want, but I like the layout of the Artist or the Album view.

Comment: Then I can't help you. I do not think there is another way. But I have not studied that too much as I would happily kill off all views except the song one and with the resources saved make it better (or even as good as it was in Snow Leopard)

Comment: I guess I’ll go with it then. Is there a way to sort the Albums in the Album column by Year instead of by Album title?

Comment: Nearly - you can sort the songs by year just click on the year header - which is normally sufficient - but not for greatest hits etc.

Comment: I meant the albums in the Column Browser, not in the Song view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119502/discussion-between-mmmmmm-and-user1785730).